# does wallet:buys:create support buying USDC?

Tags: coinbase-api

I've been looking at ways to buy USDC programmatically and I was wondering if `wallet:buys:create` endpoint from Coinbase Oauth connect support buying coins other than bitcoin or ethereum?

Comment: I'd also like to know this. The buy resources accepts a "payment_method" parameter, but a USDC wallet is not returned in the list of payment methods, it's considered a regular account. From looking at the docs it appears as if this isn't possible.

Comment: @ejfrancis are you trying to convert usdc to dai?

Comment: not specifically dai, I'm interested in any capability of using USDC via the API that the UI supports